# Нестандартный тип ресурса Android

Tags: xml, c#, android

Необходимо хранить в XML массив структур "Строка-Число-Число-Число". Можно сделать четыре параллельных массива, но это неудобно и неправильно. Программа через monodroid, поэтому эту структуру доставать потом с помощью C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а почему не сделать

```
<array>
  <node><str>test</str><first>1</first><second>2</second><third>3</third></node>
  <node><str>qwerty</str><first>11</first><second>12</second><third>13</third></node>
</array>
```

или

```
<array>
  <node str="test" f="1" s="2" t="3"/>
  <node str="qwerty" f="11" s="12" t="13"/>
</array>
```

btw, если массив будет большой, то это будет сильно подтормаживать. Но на фоне C# это мелочь:)
На java в андроид точно можно делать прекомпилированный xml, который будет грузиться заметно быстрее, но я думаю, что xml - это перебор для хранения массивов.

Comment: а как потом извлекать эти данные?

Comment: В java это относительно просто - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329308/open-xml-file-from-res-xml-in-android

А вот как в C# -  я не знаю.

Comment: В Java так же можно еще использовать XMLPullParser http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/142-urok-79-xmlpullparser-parsim-xml.html

Comment: Стандартным способом, как Ресурс, значит нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Помести свой ресурс в assets далее читай и парси как душе угодно.  Это стандартное место для нестандартных ресурсов. API Android поддерживает базовые функции чтения и проч. хэндлинга ассетов.

Comment: я спрашивал к тому, что метод Resources.ObtainTypedArray(Resource.Array.myArray); использовать не получиться - надо может и не очень сложным образом, но все-таки парсить эти строки